# Identify links with relative path in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I wrote the below code to identify external links and then add "external" class to them. I implemented this on my site, it's working fine but there is one problem it is not working correctly for "Tabs" and "Reply to comment" options. There it's adding "external" class to them but they are local links. Let me know if there's something wrong with my code.

Link for tab is like this: `<a href="#tab2" class="external">Popular</a>`

and link for reply is like this: `<a class="comment-reply-link external" href="/samsung-galaxy-ace-plus-s7500-how-to-root-and-install-custom-recovery-image/?replytocom=1044#respond" onclick="return addComment.moveForm(&quot;comment-1044&quot;, &quot;1044&quot;, &quot;respond&quot;, &quot;420&quot;)">Reply</a>`

I know that it's failing because these are not absolute links so `location.host` will not work for these links. Can you let me know how can I incorporate these links and add "local" class to them?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
var root = new RegExp(location.host);

$('a').each(function(){

    if(root.test($(this).attr('href'))){ 
        $(this).addClass('local');
    }
    else{
        // a link that does not contain the current host
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        if(url.length > 1)
        {
            $(this).addClass('external');
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of getting the attribute, get the property:

```
var url = $(this).prop('href');
```

Or:

```
var url = this.href;
```

The difference is important:

```
> $('<a href="#bar">foo</a>').prop('href')
"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17130384/identify-links-with-relative-path-in-jquery#bar"
> $('<a href="#bar">foo</a>').attr('href')
"#bar"
```

Also, I would use `location.origin` instead of `location.host`:

```
$('a').filter(function() {
    return this.href.indexOf(location.origin) === 0;
}).addClass('local');
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/q6P4W/**

Comment: The location.origin method is much better :)

Comment: Can I use the same method to add `rel="external nofollow"` to external links? In that case what should I use in place of addClass?